# Nuget list is not refreshing after manual deletion of files

Tags: nuget

We deleted some versions of packages from nexus. When we run nuget list -AllVersions, still getting the ones that are already deleted. Basically looks like the packages list is not refreshing and just appending with new versions. How to sync/refresh packages versions list?

Answer (score 0):

We deleted in database and reindexed, but nuget did not refresh the versions. So we restored the packages and deleted from the ui console.